# Update field of attribute table of a shape in selected rows with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I read the post [Accessing attribute table within shapefile and replace values?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44692/accessing-attribute-table-within-shapefile-and-replace-values), but I don't know how to include a "Where clause".

I want to update the attribute table of a shapefile. In SQL the Code looks like this:

```
alter table point_shape
    add buffer number;

update point_shape
    set buffer = a/2
    where a >0;     


alter table line_shape
    add buffer number;

update line_shape
    set buffer = a/2
    where a >0; 

alter table point_shape
    add buffer number;

update point_shape
    set buffer = sqrt(b)/acos(-1)
    where b is not null and b >0;


alter table line_shape
    add buffer number;

update line_shape
    set buffer = b/shape_len
    where b is not null and a = 0 and b>0;
```

I translated the first update statement:

```
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(point_shape)

for row in cur:
    row.setValue('buffer', row.getValue('a') / 2)
    cur.updateRow(row)
```

But where can I include the where statement?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the newer data-access cursor, they are faster. For example the [UpdateCursor](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm):

> UpdateCursor establishes read-write access to records returned from a
>   feature class or table

And an if statement:

```
import arcpy

point_shape=r'C:\path\shapefile.shp'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(point_shape,['buffer','a']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[1]>0: #row[1] = the 'a' field
            row[0]=row[1]/2 #row[0] = the 'buffer' field
            cursor.updateRow(row) #update the 'buffer' field with new value
```